# Google tags assistant reports old ads conversion tracking and multiple google Analytics tags

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager

I have a lot of tags displayed. Which are good and which are not?
My website is composed in 2 parts : WordPress + Learnybox (funnel construction) and I'm using tag assistant plugin to see if my implementation is right.

[image]

The Following tags and questions :

1. The global site tag looks OK for me
2. Google Ads Conversion >> I don't know why it's appearing here especially that it refers to an erased conversion on AdWords and it doesn't exist any more in Google Tag Manager
3. Old GA tag >> Do I need to delete it?
4. Duplicate GA tag >> may be integrated with a WordPress Addon so I need to delete it also right?
5. GTM tag, so OK